# Ubuntu 10.04 resolution issues with 2560x1440 screen

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, resolution, ubuntu-10.04

I am having issues adjusting the screen resolution of my ubuntu 10.04 OS. My relatively-new laptop has a native resolution of 2560x1440, which makes everything microscopic and quasi-unreadable.

When I go to "display settings," it says "unknown monitor," and lists 2560x1440 as the only possible resolution.

Under normal circumstances, this would be an easy fix: install ubuntu 14.04, which has lots of nice features for working with high-resolution screens. **Unfortunately, the work I am doing requires that I use 10.04.**

My objective is to reduce the system-wide resolution. I suspect it relates to the fact that 10.04 does not come preinstalled with my the driver for my Intel HD 4400 graphics.

Intel has released a graphics-driver installer, but it is not compatible with 10.04 (and they unhelpfully remove links to old versions).

Should I search for the driver manually, or is there something else I should try first?

EDIT: Intel Haswell graphics 4400, so I can't use the AMD driver-fixer

Comment: Should be on http://www.askubuntu.com

Comment: ok, posting there as well.

Comment: Please do not post the same question in two sites because it makes two copies if the question is migrated over.  Remove this copy please.